# How to sort column in Vuetify datatable?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a Vuetify Datatable component with server side data.  I would like to sort the data in the client side with what I am currently displaying.  But when I click on the column to sort it does not do anything.  The column contains string values.

The following is my datatable:

```
<v-data-table
    :page="page"
    :pageCount="numberOfPages"
    :headers="headers"     
    :items="services"
    :options.sync="options"
    :server-items-length="totalElements"
    :loading="loading"    
     :custom-filter="filterOnlyCapsText"
    class="elevation-1"
    @update:page="updatePagination"    
    :items-per-page="itemsPerPage"
    @update:items-per-page="setItemsPerPage"   
  >
```

My Vuejs code:

```
 data() {
    return {
      headers: [
        {
          text: "Service",
          value: "name",
          sortable: true,
        },
        {
          text: "Application",
          value: "application.name",
        },
        {
          text: "Description",
          value: "description",
        },
        {
          text: "Endpoint",
          value: "endpoint",
        },
        {
          text: "Environment",
          value: "environmentList",
        },
      ],
      page: 1,
      totalElements: 0,
      numberOfPages: 0,
      services: [],
      loading: true,
      options: {},
      itemsPerPage: 0,
      search: "",
    };
  },

  options: {
    handler() {
      console.log("handler got called");
    },
    deep: true,
  },
```

I am not sure what is needed to get the column to sort on the client side.  Is there a listener that I need to hook in?

Thanks

Comment: Can you share a working example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use server-side paging and need to implement this functionality by appropriate API calls when events

```
update:page, update:sortBy, update:options
```

emitted.

This is correct behavior because usually, you need to sort the whole data set, but not the current page.

Option which enable server-side behaviour:
**server-items-length**

Defining this prop will disable the built-in sorting and pagination.

Comment: your answer is totally correct, and I have it working like this but there are some cases when I'd like to sort on client-side only available records, such as: adding a new record, I send the data to the server but I also want to inject it in the table on correct position, or in case of an error during a delete when I'm removing the record from table before waiting for server response I might need to inject it again on it's position ... it would have been nice if it would have been automatically sorted on client-side too as soon as data has been changed ...